# Embedding an exe file in C# console?

Tags: c#, python, console, exe, embedding

I wish to embed an exe file (particularly "python.exe", the interpreter of Python 2.7) in my C# Console Application, meaning I want the user to enter commands, receive the interpreter's output into a string variable and use Console.WriteLine to print that output. My code so far is:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:/Python27/python.exe");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

if (process != null)
{
    while (true)
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
        process.StandardInput.Close();

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

I can write "print 5" and get the correct output, but when writing it again I get the following error:

> Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.

I believe this error is because I close the StandardInput, but without that line of code I don't get any output at all. What can I use to send multiple commands to the exe?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you call process.StandardInput.Flush() instead of Close()?

Comment: Have you considered using IronPython?

Comment: Calling this "embedding" is very unorthodox. :)

Comment: I definitely second the IronPython suggestion.  I don't think you can handle an exe like this.  I've been playing with embedding IronPython in a c# 4.0 app.  It's not to bad to do.  It takes surprisingly little code - not a whole lot more than you have in your example above.

Comment: I tried using IronPython, problem is I'm using several libraries that come as .PYD files and therefore can be used only with CPython.

Answer (score 1):

Call `process.StandardInput.Flush()` instead. Flush makes any buffered TextWriter write all of its input to the destination, which is what's happening here - you're calling `Close()` which has the side effect of flushing the buffers as well as closing the stream.

See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.flush.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, I'm the one who posted the question (was at my friend's house). Replacing the `Close()` to `Flush()` doesn't work, it doesn't even run the first command I put...

Comment: Found this comment on StreamReader.ReadToEnd() - "ReadToEnd assumes that the stream knows when it has reached an end. For interactive protocols in which the server sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection, ReadToEnd might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end, and should be avoided." It appears that using the .EndOfStream property on a StreamReader also causes an infinite block. So the question then is,  why are you doing this? You may need to rethink your approach. Mark Byers had a good suggestion regarding Iron Python.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to the question, I tried using IronPython. Problem is I'm using several libraries that come as .PYD files and therefore can be used only with CPython.